# SAS - ERROR: Indexes cannot be created for the NWAY aggregation.

Tags: sas, olap, olap-cube

I am trying to recreate my OLAP cube. The cube already exists. Then I delete the physical cube with

```
DELETE_PHYSICAL
```

After this the short

```
PROC OLAP
```

follows.
My job fails in batch with the error message

```
NOTE: The cube registration was found.
ERROR: Indexes cannot be created for the NWAY aggregation.
NOTE: Number of NWAY records: 32899296
```

Could someone tell me please why it fails? My other tests worked fine, but there the cube / detail table only contained 12,000,000 rows. Is it possible, that the number of rows is too large for NWAY-aggregation?

Here is the short pro olap code:

```
PROC OLAP
   CUBE                   = "/XXX"
   DELETE_PHYSICAL;


   METASVR
     HOST        = "XXX"
     PORT        = xxx
     USERID      = "XXX"
     PW          = "XXX"
     olap_schema="XXX";

RUN;

PROC OLAP
   CUBE                   = "/XXX";


   METASVR
     HOST        = "XXX"
     PORT        = xxx
     USERID      = "XXX"
     PW          = "XXX"
     olap_schema="XXX";

RUN;
```

Thanx!

Comment: You seem to suspect that it is due to size, so maybe you could try the following 2 things: (1) Reduce this table's size and try again to see if that makes it pass. (2) Enable some additional options to track performance: PROC OPTIONS GROUP=(SORT MEMORY PERFORMANCE); RUN;

Comment: @Shorack: Enabled options with your code example before processing proc olap. However what do I have to do with the memsize, etc.? It does not show the utilization while performing proc olap... So I can't say if it fails on too less memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an index on the nway is not possible with given preferences. So I added following options in proc olap (NOINDEX NO_NWAY):

```
PROC OLAP
   CUBE                   = "/xxx"
   DATA                   = xxx.xxx
   DRILLTHROUGH_TABLE     = xxx.xxx
   PATH                   = '/xxx'
   DESCRIPTION            = 'xxx'
   NOINDEX
   NO_NWAY;

   METASVR
    HOST        = "xxx"
    PORT        = xxx
    USERID      = "xxx"
    PW          = "xxx"
    olap_schema="xxx";
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me that you have too many unique values (not necessarily too many rows, but too many unique combinations) such that it can't create an index properly in the space allocated.

Look at [this paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/319-2009.pdf) for some suggestions.  In particular, look at ASYNCINDEXLIMIT and INDEXSORTSIZE - see if you can increase those some to allow it to build.  A good way to find out how close you are is to run the PROC OLAP with a subset of your complete dataset, specifically with a subset of the unique values of your variable(s) of interest, to see if you can do (say) half or one quarter of your data within your current limits.

If you were able to create 12MM rows but not 32MM rows, then at minimum you might try doubling the size limits and see if that works.  SAS tends to be overly conservative in its default sizes.

You might also try turning on `OPTION MSGLEVEL=I` as that should give you some additional information as to the sizes of the index it is trying to create.